# Python: Creating a table in Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

Following is the Code to create a sqlite3 table in python.

```
db=sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
db.execute('create table links' +
       '(id integer, submitter_id integer, submitted_time integer, '+
       'votes integer , title text, url text)')
```

After creating a table `links` we add columns so we add the `+` sign then again after 
`submitted_time` there is `+` sign and then `'vote.......... , url text)'`)

I don't understand why we add the `+` sign for the columns to add.

Answer (score 3):

The `+` operators concatenate the *Python* string objects. They are actually not needed here, as Python automatically joins adjacent string literals on a logical line.

Without the `+` operators the code would work still:

```
db.execute('create table links'
   '(id integer, submitter_id integer, submitted_time integer, '
   'votes integer , title text, url text)')
```

They are not part of the SQL syntax.

Personally, I'd the `"""` or `'''` triple-quote multi-line string literal syntax to define SQL statements, because extra whitespace doesn't matter here:

```
db.execute('''
    create table links (
        id integer,
        submitter_id integer,
        submitted_time integer,
        votes integer,
        title text, 
        url text)
    ''')
```

Comment: Ty i got confused to use it or not